How do I solve a problem where a textarea wont show updated value after form submits
I have a php form that submits values into a mysql dB. It all works fine and the data updates in the dB, but when I submit the form the textarea doesnt show the update value. All fields show the original values fine before submit. Text inputs show the update values fine but not the textarea. If I refresh the page after submit it shows the updated value. Can anyone help with this please. I have searched a lot of a solution but no luck.
PHP CODE
$query = "SELECT about FROM table WHERE id = 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Set default values if no existing data

$about = $row['about'] ?? '';

// Initialize message variables
$message = "";
$updated = false;

// Step 3: Handle form submission (if form is submitted)
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $newAbout = $_POST['about'];

    // Check if anything has changed before updating
    if ($newAbout !== $about) {
        // Update record in the database
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE static_pages SET about = ? WHERE id = 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $newAbout);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            // On successful update, fetch the updated record
            $row['about'] = $newAbout;
            $message = "Record updated successfully!";
            $updated = true;
        } else {
            $message = "Error updating record: " . $stmt->error;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        // If no changes made, show a message
        $message = "No changes were made.";
    }
}

Form Code
<form method="POST" action="">
<textarea id="about" name="about" rows="20"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($about); ?></textarea>     
<button class="button_blue">Update</button>
</form>


This code is written exactly to show the old value. If you want to show the new value, then you has to show it, not the old one. However, the best solution would be to do a redirect after POST, as it's required anyway. So your code will start working the way you want

Actually I think I see the problem. I should use  not 

Doing a redirect has nothing to do with solving the problem.

Can you please explain why I should do a redirect anyway

First UPDATE and then SELECT. But as mentioned before, it's best to do it in two separate requests, one POST and another GET.

@user1823053 "Doing a redirect has nothing to do with solving the problem" - doing a redirect would solve your problem and is typically best practice (PRG). Reloading the script would fetch the new value from the database AFTER it has been updated. Although a redirect isn't the only solution - you could also assign the $about value later in the script (after the db update) or reassign the new value to $about after updating the db record.

This was the problem, no redirect needed to fix it - I should use  not 

I should use <?= htmlspecialchars($row['about']) ?> not <?php echo htmlspecialchars($about); ?> for the textarea value.

Problem
The issue is that $about is set to the original database value at the start of the script. After the database is updated, the updated value is not reassigned to $about, so the textarea still displays the old value (the one you initially set to $about).

Solution
After successfully updating the database, you need to update the $about variable so that the textarea displays the new value.
Updated PHP
<?php
$query = "SELECT about FROM table WHERE id = 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$about = $row['about'] ?? '';

$message = "";
$updated = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $newAbout = $_POST['about'];

    if ($newAbout !== $about) {
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE static_pages SET about = ? WHERE id = 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $newAbout);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            // Update the $about variable with the new value
            $about = $newAbout;
            $message = "Record updated successfully!";
            $updated = true;
        } else {
            $message = "Error updating record: " . $stmt->error;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $message = "No changes were made.";
    }
}
?>


<form method="POST" action="">
    <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="20"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($about); ?></textarea>     
    <button class="button_blue">Update</button>
</form>


Surely you understand there must be a redirect?

Yes ideally there should be a redirect but it is not required to fix the issue described in the post. The simplest solution is assigning the submitted form value to $about after the database update. This avoids the need to fetch the updated value from the database and directly solves the problem of the textarea displaying the old value. A redirect would also solve the problem but would clear their $message variable, and he would then have to introduce a method of carrying his $message variable across the redirect. My solution solves the issue in the post without introducing new ones.

It says "a library of detailed, high-quality answers" not a collection quick and dirty hacks.

I dont think you guys understand my code. This $row['about'] = $newAbout; has the new value already. Thanks anyway.
